# Heroku - Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/dist/index.html'

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my Angular app on heroku, but getting following error:

Project Structure :

My `index.html` is within `src` folder

[image]

**Heroku Logs:**

```
2018-12-06T10:30:46.837610+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-12-06T10:30:50.434505+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-12-06T10:30:50.434529+00:00 app[web.1]: > music-app@0.0.0 start /app
2018-12-06T10:30:50.434531+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2018-12-06T10:30:50.434532+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-12-06T10:30:51.276734+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-12-06T10:30:51.217887+00:00 app[web.1]: Server started running..
2018-12-06T10:30:51.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-12-06T10:31:05.060270+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=boulder-app.herokuapp.com request_id=69ed1cd2-fb68-499a-9568-bfb3af482188 fwd="115.112.65.146" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=58ms status=404 bytes=380 protocol=https
2018-12-06T10:31:05.049971+00:00 app[web.1]:  Fetching from../app/dist/index.html
2018-12-06T10:31:05.060851+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/dist/index.html'
```

**My Package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "music-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot -prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "express":"^4.15.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  },
  "engines":{
    "node":"~8.14.0",
    "npm":"~5.0.0"
  }
}
```

**My server.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);

//PATH LOCATION STARTEGY

app.get('/*', function(req,res){
  const fullPath = path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
  console.log(" Fetching from.." + fullPath);
    res.sendFile(fullPath);
})

console.log('Server started running..');

//Changed to run on Heroku
```

Comment: is the error shown after deploying the app after building the app ?

Comment: also you are pointing to the dist folder  so make sure you have build the angular app using `ng build --prod`

Comment: after building your angular app for production you can find that dist file has now your minified project file in a folder with your project name  so you will have to make changes    `const fullPath = path.join(__dirname + '/dist/project_folder/index.html');`

Comment: @JoelJoseph : I see no error, I get success message. Check Heroku Logs in question body.

Comment: Also, Im using `"postinstall": "ng build --aot -prod"`  still I don't see any `dist` folder created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got The Answer:

In the server.js, I had to change my path from `/dist` to `/dist/music-app` and
from `/dist/index.html` to `/dist/music-app/index.html`.

where, `music-app` is the name attribute [`"name": "music-app"`] in my package.json file.

Comment: More precisely `app-name` is the name attribute `"outputPath": "dist/app-name"` in **angular.json** file.        I had the same problem when changed `name` only in `package.json` file and after used it like wrong build path.